# Retrieving List inside the hashmap.

Tags: java, list, jsp, collections, hashmap

I am trying to retrieve the List values from my hashmap but it is displaying com.action.ReportClass@10da25f. Here ReportClass is Pojo class where i set my resultset data in it.

```
 package com.pkg;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class JanuaryAction {
    private String from; // creating variables to access input values.
    private String to; // creating variables to access input values.
    Map abc1 = new HashMap(); // Getting the map objects to store tha values

    public Map getAbc1() { /* Creating the setters and getters */
        return abc1;
    }

    public void setAbc1(Map abc1) {
        this.abc1 = abc1;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(Map<String, String> abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map = new HashMap<String, List<ReportClass>>(); // Using
                                                                                    // Map
                                                                                    // interface
                                                                                    // implementing
                                                                                    // hashmap

    public Map<String, List<ReportClass>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, List<ReportClass>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        String fromdate = getFrom();
        System.out.println(fromdate);
        String todate = getTo();
        System.out.println(todate);

        Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultset = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >='"
                        + fromdate + "' AND OrderDate <='" + todate + "' GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace");

        while (resultset.next()) {
            String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);// get the first column
                                                        // in marketplace
            String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);// get the second column
                                                        // in orderdate
            Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);// get the third column in
                                                        // datamount
            Integer count = resultset.getInt(4);// get the fourth column in
                                                // count
            Double result = resultset.getDouble(5); // get the fifth column in
                                                    // result
            ReportClass a = new ReportClass(); // create an object to access
                                                // pojo class.

            a.setMarketplace(marketplace); // setting the values in pojo class
            a.setOrderdate(orderdate);
            a.setDataamount(datamount);
            a.setCount(count);
            a.setResult(result);

            if (map.get(marketplace) != null) { // if the value in marketplace
                                                // is null then go to else
                                                // statement or go to if
                                                // statement.
                map.get(marketplace).add(a); // using the key add one complete
                                                // row values from a to
                                                // marketplace
            } else {
                List<ReportClass> optionsVO = new ArrayList<ReportClass>(); // create
                                                                            // a
                                                                            // list
                                                                            // optionsVo
                optionsVO.add(a); // store Reportclass values in List.
                map.put(marketplace, optionsVO); // storing it in map.
                /* System.out.println(map.get(marketplace).toString()); */
            }

        }
        Set s = map.entrySet(); // A map entry (key-value pair).creating Set
                                // interface.
        Iterator i = s.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {

            List<ReportClass> tempList = (List<ReportClass>) ((Entry) i.next()).getValue(); // creating
                                                                                            // a
                                                                                            // temporary
                                                                                            // list

            for (ReportClass reportClassObj : tempList) {
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getMarketplace());// display
                                                                    // values.
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getDataamount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getOrderdate());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getCount());
                System.out.println(reportClassObj.getResult());
            }
        }

        /* System.out.println(map.size()); */
        return "success";
    }
}
```

in my jsp i have a code.

```
<s:iterator var="studentEntry" status="stat" value="map.entrySet()">  
Student Key: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getKey()}"/> 
Student Value: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getValue()}"/><br>  

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: You need to override the `toString` method in `ReportClass`.

Comment: I would appreciate you if you can show me an example as i am newbie

Comment: Can you do a google search with the above content that I wrote. Search for `"Overriding toString in Java"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in your reportclass

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "orderdate is: " +orderdate+ ", No of order is:  "+dataamount+ ",  Total Order is: "  +count+  ",  Reuslt is:  "+result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are directly printing `ReportClass` object and it prints hashcode value of it. you need to override `toString()` method of the class to get the meaningful textual representation of the object.

I guess you are using eclipse. Just right click on the editor and click `override toString`. There you can select which fields to put in representation.

Here is an example.

package com.compare;

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Prasad");
        person.setLastName("kharkar");

        System.out.println(person);

    }

}
```

This will generate following output.

```
Person [firstName=Prasad, lastName=kharkar]
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)

Comment: can u just show me how do i implement in my case. i am not able to figure it out how to do.